# How to get the changed radio buttons value in action class in struts

Tags: jsp, struts-1

I am working on an application using struts 1.3.
In my JSP page, a table shows all the registered user details as one record per row.

Each row contains two radio buttons, FM and "ODP". During user registration the default value will be  FM for all users.

Admin has to select particular users and change their option to ODP. Admin can change the option for all users or can skip some of the users. After pressing submit button, how do I read all changed radio buttons values one by one to update the database according to Admin's selection.

Whenever I press submit button after changing the values, I get the same old values in my action class. What can I do to access the new values of the selected radio button?

Any help  on this will be highly appreciated.

Here is my sample code-

JSP-

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@taglib uri="/WEB-INF/struts-html.tld" prefix="html" %>
<%@taglib uri="/WEB-INF/struts-bean.tld" prefix="bean" %>
<%@taglib uri="/WEB-INF/struts-logic.tld" prefix="logic" %>


<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
    <title>JSP Page</title>

</head>

<body>
    <div style="color:red">
   <!--     <html:errors/> --> 
    </div>
    <html:form  action="/User.dp?parameter=save" >
    <div>
<div style="float:left;padding-left:30px;">UserName</div> 
<div style="float:left;padding-left:30px;">Address</div>
<div style="float:left;padding-left:30px;">Satus</div>
<div style="float:left;padding-left:30px;">Radio</div>
<div style="clear:both;"></div>
</div>
<logic:iterate  id="listUserIdDetails" name="UserForm" property="listUserId">
<p>
<div>
<div style="float:left;padding-left:30px;"><bean:write name="listUserIdDetails" property="name"/> </div> 
<div style="float:left;padding-left:60px;"><bean:write name="listUserIdDetails" property="address"/></div>
<div style="float:left;padding-left:60px;"><bean:write name="listUserIdDetails" property="active"/></div>
 <div style="float:left;padding-left:60px;"><html:radio indexed="true" property="active" name="listUserIdDetails" value="001"   /> <html:radio indexed="true"  property="active" name="listUserIdDetails"  value="002" /></div>
  </div><div style="clear:both;"></div>
  </logic:iterate>
  <html:submit value="submit"  ></html:submit>
       </html:form>
  </body>
  </html>
```

Here is my action class-

```
  public ActionForward save(ActionMapping mapping, ActionForm form,
        HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws Exception {
    UserListForm userForm = (UserListForm) form;
    ArrayList alist=userForm.getListUserId();

     for(int i=1;i<alist.size();i++)
     {
         UserListForm ulist= (UserListForm)alist.get(i);
        System.out.println("User:"+ulist.getName()+":"+ulist.getActive()); 
     }
    System.out.println(userForm.getName()+":"+userForm.getActive());

        return mapping.findForward("success");

  }
 }
```

Form-

```
    public class UserListForm extends ActionForm {

private String name=null;
private String address=null;
private String active=null;
private ArrayList<UserListForm> listUserId=null;
public ArrayList<UserListForm> getListUserId() {
    return listUserId;
}
public void setListUserId(ArrayList<UserListForm> listUserId) {
    this.listUserId = listUserId;
}
    ......
    ......
    }
```

Please help me to get the changed values in my action class if admin change the radio button.

Answer (score 3):

I think you should do something along this line.

```
<html:radio name="userListForm " property="myRadio" value="FM" >FM</html:radio>
<html:radio name="userListForm " property="myRadio" value="ODP" >ODP</html:radio>
```

---

```
public class UserListForm { 
    private String myRadio;
    public String getMyRadio() {
        return myRadio;     
    }
    public void setMyRadio(String myRadio) {
        this.myRadio = myRadio;
    }
}
```

---

```
public class MyAction{
     public ActionForward save(ActionMapping mapping, ActionForm form,
        HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws Exception {

        UserListForm userForm = (UserListForm) form;
        String radioSelected = userForm.getMyRadio();//This will return the value of the "myRadio" in this case it will be either "FM" or "ODP" depending on which one you selected. 
}
```

`String radioSelected = userForm.getMyRadio()` ---This statement will return the value of the radio button that was selected. So you can check the value returned by this and do as you want. 
for eg.

```
if(radioSelected.equals("FM"){
     //do something
}else if(radioSelected.equals("ODB"){
     //do something else. 
}
```

Comment: What does the method "setOutboundSourceTable" stands for? It should be "setMyRadio" I think.